# Fabric.js: on text submit, create an object for each line

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

here is my fuction to add text objects on Fabric, is there a way to modify it so it creates several objects (one for each line) if line breaks are detected in input ?

```
self.addText = function(str) {
        str = str || 'Votre Texte...';

        var object = new FabricWindow.Text(str, self.textDefaults);
        object.id = self.createId();

        self.addObjectToCanvas(object);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have line break \n in your string. So let's try this

```
let strArr = str.split('\n');
strArr.forEach(s => {
    let object = new FabricWindow.Text(s, self.textDefaults);
    object.id = self.createId(); //you should probably start using es6 arrow syntax to avoid having to use self

    self.addObjectToCanvas(object);
})
```